# Is nextJS backend serverless?

Tags: next.js, serverless

I am trying to understand [NextJs](https://nextjs.org/). I understand that nextJs is a React Based framework. I also understand that NextJs has the functionality of creating a backend using nodeJS. Is this backend made up of serverless functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NextJS is a front-end framework at its core. The Node.js backend it creates is in support of its ability to perform [SSR/ISR data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview).

When you say

> is this backend made up of serverless functions?

I think you are referring to the NextJS `pages/api` directory, which provides an easy way to create API endpoints. While you can choose to treat these as serverless functions (Vercel, the creators of NextJS, [provide an easy way to do this](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions)), you can also choose to have these API endpoints served any way you want, like by an Express server for example. To do this you would have code in your `pages/api/<api-route-name>.js` file that fetches data from another server. You can choose also to not use the `pages/api` directory at all and make your server calls how you normally would in a React app.

You may also opt to customize NextJS routing/server behavior completely by [using a custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server). While NextJS does provide an opinionated structure, you can really do whatever you want on the backend.